# Port Forwarding with AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, portforwarding

I am interested in having a script access a database on my local computer to do some analysis on it. I have played around with EC2 and am able to port forward my MySQL database from my local computer to my EC2 instance and read it in in EC2 in Python. However, since Lambda is cheaper, I was wondering if this was achievable with Lambda? Can Lambda be configured to access another computer's database?

Comment: What performance issues are you experiencing when doing everything on your local computer that makes you want to try Lambda? Is there a particular capability that you wish to improve?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions can **connect to the Internet by default**. Therefore, anything that is accessible on the Internet is accessible to a Lambda function.

However, your home computer is probably **behind a router**, which will prevent direct access to your resources. You could configure the router to do **Port Forwarding** (which might be the same as you mentioned in your Question) such that your database is accessible on the Internet. (Warning: Not good for security!)

However, the setup you describe is probably not worthwhile. It is normally **best to have a database 'close' to the application** in terms of latency and bandwidth. If you are retrieving lots of data, your Internet connection would probably slow things down to give worse performance than on your laptop. On the other hand, if you are running complex database queries that return few rows, it could be feasible.